# Expression of incompatible type 'id<MKAnnotation>'

Tags: ios, objective-c, mkmapview, mkannotation

I have this piece of code

```
- (void)pinDropped {
StoreData *myStore = [StoreData sharedStore];

for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < annotations.count; i++) {

    MapViewController *ann = [[_mapView annotations] objectAtIndex:i];

    NSString *myStoreString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", myStore.myUebergabe];
    NSString *myAnnTitleString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", ann.title];


    if ([myStoreString isEqual:myAnnTitleString]) {
        [_mapView selectAnnotation:[_mapView.annotations objectAtIndex:i] animated:YES];

    }
```

}
}

which creates this warning in Xcode at *ann:

```
 Initializing 'MapViewController *__strong' with an expression of incompatible type 'id<MKAnnotation>'
```

How get I rid of this warning? 
Everything works fine despite of the warning.

Thank you very much for pointing me in the right direction.
Martin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
MapViewController *ann = [[_mapView annotations] objectAtIndex:i];
```

to:

```
id<MKAnnotation> ann = [[_mapView annotations] objectAtIndex:i];
```

since `[_mapView annotations]` returns an array of `id<MKAnnotation`, not an array of `MapViewController`.